# VBA Change color of shape

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I have macro in excel, which creates visio drawing. This macro creates shape on the first page. After that, i`d like to color this shape, but im unable to do this. Until my shape was something like "box" or "square" from basic shapes/etc. it was ok. But with this shape i can't do similar actions.
I have found, that my shape is group of shapes. It contains 12 other shapes, and thing called "RootShape".
If i try to rotate, or move shape - i can. (and it's parts of course) But i can't color it.
I have tried to call shape like:

```
shpObj."do_the_coloring"
shpObj.RootShape."do_the_coloring"
shpObj.Shapes.Item(x)."do_the_coloring"
```

But i still had no sucess.

This is the full code

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

   Dim AppVisio As visio.Application
   Dim docsObj As visio.Documents 
   Dim DocObj As visio.Document 
   Dim stnObj As visio.Document 
   Dim mastObj As visio.master 
   Dim pagsObj As visio.Pages 
   Dim pagObj As visio.Page 
   Dim shpObj As visio.shape 

   Set AppVisio = CreateObject("visio.application")      
   AppVisio.Visible = True
   
   
   Set docsObj = AppVisio.Documents
   Set DocObj = docsObj.Add("Detailed Network Diagram.vst")

   Set pagsObj = AppVisio.ActiveDocument.Pages
   Set pagObj = pagsObj.Item(1) 
   Set stnObj = AppVisio.Documents.Item("periph_m.vss") 'i use this stencil
   
   Set mastObj = stnObj.Masters("Mainframe") 'trying to color this shape
  
  Set shpObj = pagObj.Drop(mastObj, 2, 2) 'creating a figure
  'trying to paint it
   shpObj.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "rgb(1,220,2)"
   shpObj.RootShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "rgb(1,220,2)"
   shpObj.Shapes.Item(4).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "rgb(1,220,2)"
   'other method
   shpObj.Cells("Fillforegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(255,0,0)"
   shpObj.RootShape.Cells("Fillforegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(255,0,0)"
   shpObj.Shape.Item(4).Cells("Fillforegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(255,0,0)"
   'other method
   shpObj.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB (255, 0, 0)
   shpObj.RootShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB (255, 0, 0)
   shpObj.Shapes.Item(4).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB (255, 0, 0)
   'other similar methods
    ...
    End Sub
```

I tried to add rows/paint other rows.
I tried to paint with color codes (ex 2 for red)
I also tried to call shape as object from page (like this, but not just like this, of course)

```
pagObj.Shapes.Item(1)
```

So, i can do with the shape almost whatever i want, but not the coloring. What could be the possible problem? (my target is shpObj.Shapes.Item(4))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found, what i have missed. I needed change this:

```
shpObj.Shapes.Item(4).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowFill, visFillForegnd).FormulaU = "rgb(1,220,2)"
```

to this

```
shpObj.Shapes.Item(4).CellsSRC(visSectionFillGradientStops, 1, visGradientStopColor).FormulaU = "rgb(1,220,2)"
```

shapes, which "mainframe" consists of are having complicated coloring scheme (because of filling). And this was the problem.
If i change "1" to "0" I can color other part of gradient

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the shape has a number of sub-shapes and your challenge is to track down which sub-shape/s carries the fill color.

To track this sort of problem down using the [Drawing Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-your-drawing-in-the-drawing-explorer-window-298c7c17-7d6e-4a82-9a7f-fdc32910b59b), the [macro recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/record-macros-in-visio-05c29ac5-922d-4fd4-8d60-8e2ccd3ecc5a) and the [Event Monitor](https://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2008/06/using-the-visio-event-monitor-tool.html) tools can be helpful.  Also, open up the ShapeSheet of the various sub-shapes and see what happens when you apply a manual change in the UI.

One difference to be aware of is that when you apply a fill color to a group shape the color is propogated down through all of the sub-shapes (unless they're locked), but in code you're only addressing one shape at a time.

For the MainFrame shape (in the 'Network and Peripherals' stencil), the top group shape has no geometry and so none of line or fill formating will have any effect.

If you inspect the shape in the Drawing Explorer you'll see that the fill is made visible in 1st and 3rd sub-shapes.

Unfortunately they lack any other identifier apart from their index position.

So your fill call should addressing

`shpObj.Shapes[1].CellsU("FillForegnd").FormulaU = "RGB(255,0,0)"`

and likewise for

`shpObj.Shapes[3]...`

Re `RootShape` - this property just gets a reference to the top level group shape.  In your scenario, `shpObj.RootShape` just returns a reference to itself.  It's really only useful for sub-shapes.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer, but i literally wrote that i'm faceing a group of shapes, i know how many are there and that i can manipulate each of them, but can't color them. And i asked for other coloring method.
Unfortunately, your answer decribes things i already wrote in question and even provided code examples. But i have solved my problem and left an answer. You can read it,if you wish. P.s. Advice to use macro recording is good.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was looking at PERIME_M.vssx (the 2d version) and not the one you mentioned: PERIPH_M.vssx (the 3D version).  The 2d version only has 3 sub-shapes and so I assumed your problem was addressing number 4.  Glad you're all fixed.